# Integer Arithmetic Coding misunderstanding of parameters

Tags: information-theory, data-compression

Given this alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ where $P(a) = 2/5$, $P(b) = 2/5$, $P(c) = 1/5$. Encode this string : $bcba$.

I have to encode this using 5 bits.

I have been looking in the Introduction to Data Compression book, and I can't figure out what my "Total Count" is and neither my $n_i$.

$F_x(k) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k n_i}{TotalCount}$

How do I calculate the (What's k? is the question pretty much):

Cumulative_Count(k) $= \sum_{i=1}^k n_i$

Is my total count = 4? or $2^5$

Comment: Are you asking what the exercise is asking you?  If so, you should include the exact and complete statement of the exercise, and give us a full citation (book title, author, exercise number, chapter).  Are you asking the meaning of some terms?  If so, can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $n_i$ is the number of occurrences of the $i$th symbol, and TotalCount is the total number of occurrences (so $\sum_{i=1}^m n_i$, where $m$ is the number of symbols). So $F_x(k)$ counts the relative fractions of the first $k$ symbols.

To know for sure, you should check your textbook, which surely defines everything somewhere. You might have to read earlier sections or chapters.